# SQL Managed Instance Trigger blocking CDC

Tags: sql

I am facing a situation where my trigger is blocking CDC from being enabled on my database. I have tried to do the following but without success:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [DDL]
ON ALL SERVER
FOR CREATE_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE, DROP_TABLE, CREATE_INDEX, ALTER_INDEX, DROP_INDEX, CREATE_VIEW, ALTER_VIEW, DROP_VIEW, CREATE_PROCEDURE, ALTER_PROCEDURE, DROP_PROCEDURE,
    CREATE_FUNCTION, ALTER_FUNCTION, DROP_FUNCTION, DROP_TRIGGER, ALTER_TRIGGER, CREATE_TRIGGER, CREATE_USER, ALTER_USER, DROP_USER, CREATE_ROLE, ALTER_ROLE, DROP_ROLE,
    CREATE_SCHEMA, ALTER_SCHEMA, DROP_SCHEMA, CREATE_LOGIN, ALTER_LOGIN, DROP_LOGIN, GRANT_DATABASE, ALTER_DATABASE, CREATE_DATABASE, DROP_DATABASE, ADD_ROLE_MEMBER, DROP_ROLE_MEMBER,
    ALTER_INSTANCE, CREATE_SERVER_ROLE, ALTER_SERVER_ROLE, DROP_SERVER_ROLE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @event xml;
    SET @event = EVENTDATA();

    -- Exclude CDC related events
    IF @event.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)').value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') NOT LIKE '%create user cdc%'
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @ipAddress VARCHAR(50);
        SELECT @ipAddress = client_net_address
        FROM sys.dm_exec_connections
        WHERE session_id = @@SPID;

        INSERT INTO [DBATools].[dbo].Table
        VALUES
        (
            REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(50), @event.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/PostTime)')), 'T', ' '),
            CONVERT(varchar(150), @event.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/LoginName)')),
            CONVERT(varchar(150), @event.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/UserName)')),
            CONVERT(varchar(150), @event.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/DatabaseName)')),
            CONVERT(varchar(150), @event.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/SchemaName)')),
            CONVERT(varchar(150), @event.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)')),
            CONVERT(varchar(150), @event.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectType)')),
            CONVERT(varchar(max), @event.query('data(/EVENT_INSTANCE/TSQLCommand/CommandText)')),
            @ipAddress
        );
    END;
END;
GO
```

So whenever I run cdc related procs below I get errors:
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_help_change_data_capture

exec sp_cdc_enable_db

```
Could not update the metadata that indicates database DB1 is enabled for Change Data Capture. The failure occurred when executing the command 'create user cdc'. The error returned was 15562: 'The module being executed is not trusted. Either the owner of the database of the module needs to be granted authenticate permission, or the module needs to be digitally signed.'. Use the action and error to determine the cause of the failure and resubmit the request.
```

Also it doesnt want to create the cdc schema as well as the cdc tables

not sure if am missing something

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh this is Azure SQL-managed instance